# How to show legend like Maps' in Line diagram in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highcharts, 
I want to have a legend like Maps instead of default Line graph's legend, for specific line only.

For example, using this legend

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/color-axis/

```
        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            borderWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.85)',
            floating: true,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25
        },
```

instead of

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

```
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
```

in this example, having "Tokyo" numbers in details.

Any Ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's not supported, but you can try to add such functionality from maps to the standard charts: http://jsfiddle.net/w9nuha8n/

```
(function (H) {
    // add colorAxis
    H.seriesTypes.line.prototype.axisTypes = ['xAxis', 'yAxis', 'colorAxis']; 
    H.seriesTypes.line.prototype.optionalAxis = 'colorAxis';

    // draw points and add setting colors
    H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.line.prototype, "translate", function (p) {
        p.call(this);
        H.seriesTypes.heatmap.prototype.translateColors.call(this);
    });

    // copy method from heatmap for color mixin
    H.seriesTypes.line.prototype.translateColors = H.seriesTypes.heatmap.prototype.translateColors; 

    // use "y" to calculate color
    H.seriesTypes.line.prototype.colorKey = 'y';
})(Highcharts);
```

Comment: Thank you, it's brilliant! Out of curiosity, can we categorize the legend in say 3 levels, to show the division result of node values? e.g, suppose that max is 30, having this function ((nodeVal / 10)+1) for the legend, makes 3 levels. where and how to use it??

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite following you. Could you show some image or provide a bit more of the description?

Comment: actually I need to categorize the legend from Maps into 3 levels, showing numbers between 1 to 10 in CAT1, numbers between 11 to 20 in CAT2, and so forth.. there must be some place to use something like ((nodeVal /10)+1) when max "nodeVal = value of each node" is 30, for example! I'll provide an image if it's not clear though.

Comment: Wouldn't be that easier to create points with already defined colors? And split them into three series? Also, is [that topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30713034/extending-highmaps-side-effect) somehow connected to your question too?